# Given an ETH wallet address - Fetch all ERC721 tokens currently owned

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, python, erc-721, nft

I would like to create an application that - given a specific wallet address - fetches and displays all NFTs/ERC721 tokens currently owned. How can this be accomplished? Are there any examples available that are performing something similar?

Comment: You can see ERC721 transactions on etherscan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cheap/simple -- use the OpenSea API.

---

Robust/exhaustive -- you'll need to write your own client. 0xcert has one we might be able to share. And it will monopolize a full server to run + stay synced.

Comment: I was having trouble finding the Image URL of the asset via Ethersan, therefore i've chose this as the best solution. It is simple to get started, the API call that helped my fetch my specific ERC721 asset was the following: https://docs.opensea.io/reference#getting-assets

Answer (score 2):

Make use of Etherscan API: https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts

There is an endpoint to `Get a list of "ERC721 - Token Transfer Events" by Address`.

Create an Etherscan free account and get an API key so you can query that API endpoint